# How can i fit a specific count of rectangles in a bigger rectangle with a given size?

Tags: algorithms

I have an area (rectangle) with a given size and i want to fit any number of smaller rectangles with variable height and width in it.

I.e.:
My rectangle is 1024x600 and i want to fit 150 smaller rectangles in it.

So basically i need an algorithm/function, where i can pass the amount of rectangles, which returns the width and height of the small rectangles.

I didn't post it on Stackoverflow because i thought it's more a mathematical problem than a, in my case, javascript problem.

If you have any links to questions which solved this problem, be free to post them. I didn't find ones that helped me :)
And sorry for possible mistakes in my text. I am not natively english ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the solution here isn't unique. For example in your example problem I could return 1024 x (600/150) or (1024/150) x 600. Both will fill your original rectangle.
You'll need to add some constraint to the problem, there aren't really any "natural" choices for this constraint - they'd have to come from whatever problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the intent is a random partition of the original rectangle and using Mathematica for coding

```
cf := ColorData["FruitPunchColors"][RandomReal[]]

rectPartition[rect_, 1] := {cf, rect};

rectPartition[rect_, 2] :=
 Module[{vert = RandomChoice[{True, False}],
   xmin = rect[[1, 1]], ymin = rect[[1, 2]],
   xmax, ymax, xdel, ydel, rand = RandomReal[{1/3, 1/2}]},
  If[Length@rect == 1,
   xmax = xmin + 1; ymax = ymin + 1,
   xmax = rect[[2, 1]]; ymax = rect[[2, 2]]];
  If[vert,
   xdel = rand (xmax - xmin);
   {cf, Rectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {xmin + xdel, ymax}],
    cf, Rectangle[{xmin + xdel, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}]},
   ydel = rand (ymax - ymin);
   {cf, Rectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymin + ydel}],
    cf, Rectangle[{xmin, ymin + ydel}, {xmax, ymax}]}]]

rectPartition[rect_, n_Integer?Positive] :=

 Module[{xmin = rect[[1, 1]], ymin = rect[[1, 2]],
   xmax, ymax, xdel, ydel,
   xrand = RandomReal[{1/3, 1/2}],
   yrand = RandomReal[{1/3, 1/2}],
   n1 = RandomInteger[{1, n - 2}], n2},
  n2 = n - n1 - 1;
  If[Length@rect == 1,
   xmax = xmin + 1; ymax = ymin + 1,
   xmax = rect[[2, 1]]; ymax = rect[[2, 2]]];
  xdel = xrand (xmax - xmin);
  ydel = yrand (ymax - ymin);
  Flatten[
   {cf, Rectangle[
     {xmin, ymin}, {xmin + xdel, ymin + ydel}],
    rectPartition[Rectangle[
      {xmin, ymin + ydel},
      {xmin + xdel, ymax}], n1],
    rectPartition[Rectangle[
      {xmin + xdel, ymin},
      {xmax, ymax}], n2]}, 1]]

nbrRectangles = 10;

Graphics[rectPartition[Rectangle[], nbrRectangles]]
```

[image]